# Error 404 when deploying a project on Vercel from GitHub without webhook

Tags: reactjs, github, vercel

Stack Overflow community!

I'm experiencing issues when trying to deploy a project from GitHub to Vercel. I'm working with the repository [ProgestAPP](https://github.com/PROGEST-DEV/ProgestAPP), and when I attempt to access the deployed application on Vercel, I get a 404 error. I'm not sure what's causing this error, and I need help to resolve it.

I've followed the standard steps to deploy from GitHub to Vercel, but it seems that something is going wrong. Here are some additional details:

- I've connected my GitHub repository to Vercel and set up the deployment manually since I'm not using a webhook.
- The build and deployment on Vercel complete without apparent errors.
- The domain provided by Vercel shows a 404 error instead of the application.
  Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has any insights into what might be causing this 404 error? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've been trying to deploy the ProgestAPP project on Vercel multiple times, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Each time I deploy, I encounter a 404 error when trying to access the application. I've followed the standard steps to deploy from GitHub to Vercel, but it seems that something is going wrong.

Here's what I've attempted:

I've connected my GitHub repository to Vercel and set up the deployment manually since I'm not using a webhook.
The build and deployment on Vercel complete without apparent errors.
However, when I visit the domain provided by Vercel, I consistently receive a 404 error instead of the application.
I'm hoping to get some guidance or advice on how to resolve this issue and have the page deploy successfully.

I attached configuration in vercel:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance!